# WCF variable lifetime/state

Tags: wcf, iis

I'm hosting my first WCF service in IIS. I have two methods, 1 to set a string variable on the WCF Service, and the other to retrieve it. The interface used is:

```
[OperationContract]
string ReturnText();

[OperationContract]
void SetText(string s);
```

BasicHttpBinding is used. Stepping through the service with the debugger from the client reveals that the value of the string is set correctly using SetText, but when I immediately do a return text, the string is back to null.

Probably a simple one I know, but I thought that all values on the WCF service were retained between opening the service connection and closing it.

Why is the value lost between the Set and Gets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default things are session-less and instances are per-call.  See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx

for some starter information, but in order to have state across the calls, you'll either need a PerSession or Single instancing mode on the server, and in the former case, configure the binding to support sessions (so that the two calls can be correlated as a result of being a part of the same session connection).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Brian, that link holds the information I need. I've added

[ServiceContract (SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]

to my interface/contract and it automagically now works!

Answer (score 2):

For volatile values, you could also just store the value in a static variable. This will also maintains its state across calls, as long as the wcf host is not recycled/restarted